# Transactional Annotation is not making my code atomic when used in conjunction with Spring Data JPA. Please suggest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Jpa in spring boot and I'm using multiple datasources in my project(not sure if this is useful info). I have a service method which has to insert data into 2 entities. The requirement is that, this method has to be atomic. It has to insert into both entities or fail for both of them. However in my case the insert into first entity is not being rolled back when there is an error inserting into second entity. Please help!!

*Note: Cannot add the entire code as there is business logic and I'm not allowed to paste it in entirety. But if there is any important piece of code needed for understanding the question. Please suggest*

**My Repositories**

```
public interface ReturnEntriesHistoryRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ReturnEntryHistory, String>{
    Optional<ReturnEntryHistory>   findById(String id);

    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public <S extends ReturnEntryHistory> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
}



public interface ReturnHistoryRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ReturnHistory, String>
{
    Optional<ReturnHistory> findById(String id);

    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public <S extends ReturnHistory> S save(S s);
}
```

**My Service**

```
    @Service
    public class ReturnsService 
    {
            @Autowired
            LaneHelper laneHelper;

            // Method which is supposed to be executed as transaction
            @Transactional(rollbackFor= {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class,},propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
            public void captureCurrentSnapshotFor(ReturnDao dao, Long storeId)
            {
                if(dao == null || dao.getReturnOrder() == null || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dao.getReturnEntries()) || storeId == null)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Either invalid Dao or Store is Null when trying to captue current snapshot of the Return");
                }
                // Fetching the repositories
                // The following lines tries to identify the data source whose repository to write to

                ReturnHistoryRepo returnHistoryRepo = laneHelper.getReturnHistoryRepository(storeId);
                ReturnEntriesHistoryRepo returnEntryHistoryRepo = laneHelper.getReturnEntriesHistoryRepository(storeId);

                // Constructing History Records
                ReturnHistory returnHistory = convertReturnToReturnHistory(dao.getReturnOrder());
                List<ReturnEntryHistory> returnEntriesHistory = dao.getReturnEntries().stream().map(entry -> convertReturnEntryToReturnEntryHistory(entry)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                // Persisting History Records
                returnHistoryRepo.save(returnHistory);
                returnEntryHistoryRepo.saveAll(returnEntriesHistory);
            }
    }
```

**My Tests**

```
        @Component
        public class TestsHelper 
        {
            private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

            @Transactional(rollbackFor= {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
            public void runCaptureCurrentSnapshotForAtomicityNegativeCase(String returnOrderUuid, Long storeId, ReturnsService returnsService )
            {
                // Creating Return Order
                Returns returnOrder = new Returns();

                returnOrder.setId(returnOrderUuid);
                returnOrder.setReturnId("FC-12345");
                returnOrder.setFcOrderId("FC-ORD-12345");
                returnOrder.setOrderId(Long.valueOf("12345"));
                returnOrder.setRefundAmount(Double.valueOf("500"));
                returnOrder.setShippingRefundAmount(Double.valueOf("0"));
                returnOrder.setStoreId(storeId);
                returnOrder.setStatus(Long.valueOf("12"));
                returnOrder.setIsFullOrderReturn("FALSE");
                returnOrder.setCreatedBy("TEST_CASE");
                returnOrder.setCreatedDate(new Date());

                // Creating Return Entries
                List<ReturnEntry> returnEntries = new ArrayList<ReturnEntry>();

                // Entry-1
                ReturnEntry entry = new ReturnEntry();
                entry.setId("TEST-123451");
                entry.setReturnId(returnOrderUuid);
                entry.setStoreId(storeId);
                entry.setLineNumber(1);
                entry.setProductId(Long.valueOf("12345"));
                entry.setProductSkuId(Long.valueOf("12345"));
                entry.setPrimaryReason("TEST-PRIMARY-REASON");
                entry.setSecondaryReason("TEST-SECONDARY-REASON");
                entry.setMrp(Double.valueOf("300"));
                entry.setRefundAmount(Double.valueOf("300"));
                entry.setStatus(Long.valueOf("12"));
                entry.setExpectedQuantity(Double.valueOf("1"));
                entry.setUnitOfMeasure("pieces");
                entry.setCreatedBy("TEST_CASE");
                entry.setCreatedDate(new Date());

                // Entry-2
                // Creating The second one with NULL id to ensure it fails
                ReturnEntry entry1 = new ReturnEntry();
        //        entry1.setId("TEST-123451");
                entry1.setReturnId(returnOrderUuid);
                entry1.setStoreId(storeId);
                entry1.setLineNumber(1);
                entry1.setProductId(Long.valueOf("12345"));
                entry1.setProductSkuId(Long.valueOf("12345"));
                entry1.setPrimaryReason("TEST-PRIMARY-REASON");
                entry1.setSecondaryReason("TEST-SECONDARY-REASON");
                entry1.setMrp(Double.valueOf("300"));
                entry1.setRefundAmount(Double.valueOf("300"));
                entry1.setStatus(Long.valueOf("12"));
                entry1.setExpectedQuantity(Double.valueOf("1"));
                entry1.setUnitOfMeasure("pieces");
                entry1.setCreatedBy("TEST_CASE");
                entry1.setCreatedDate(new Date());

                returnEntries.add(entry);
                returnEntries.add(entry1);

                ReturnDao dao = ReturnDao.builder().returnOrder(returnOrder).returnEntries(returnEntries).build();

                log.info("Capturing Snapshot:start");
                returnsService.captureCurrentSnapshotFor(dao, storeId);
                log.info("Capturing Snapshot:end ");
            }
        }

        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
        public class ReturnsServiceTest 
        {
            private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

            @Autowired
            ReturnsService returnsService;

            @Autowired
            MerchantLaneHelper merchantLaneHelper;

            @Autowired
            public TestsHelper testsHelper;

            Long                     storeId;
            String                   returnOrderUuid;
            ReturnHistoryRepo        returnHistoryRepo;

            @Test
            public void testCaptureCurrentSnapshotForAtomicityNegativeCase()
            {
                try
                {
                    testsHelper.runCaptureCurrentSnapshotForAtomicityNegativeCase(returnOrderUuid, storeId, returnsService);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }

                List<ReturnHistory> persistedReturns = returnHistoryRepo.findByReturnId(returnOrderUuid);
                assertTrue(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(persistedReturns));
            }
        }
```

**My Main Class**

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "<base package>"})
        @EnableScheduling
        @EnableAsync
        @EnableWebMvc
        @EnableKafka
        @EnableCaching
        @EnableRetry
        @EnableJms
        @EnableAutoConfiguration
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        //@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repo.package>")
        public class MainApplication{

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
            }
        }
```

When I'm trying to run the test case it's failing as the first record is not getting rolled back

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
        at com.ril.jio.integration.tests.returns.ReturnsServiceTest.testCaptureCurrentSnapshotForAtomicityNegativeCase(ReturnsServiceTest.java:294)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

The following is what is printed in logs

```
2019-12-13 11:08:33.322  INFO 19233 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    2019-12-13 11:08:33.960  WARN 19233 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
    2019-12-13 11:08:33.961 ERROR 19233 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("RETURNENTRIES_HISTORY"."UUID")
    2019-12-13 11:08:33.964 ERROR 19233 --- [           main] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
    2019-12-13 11:08:33.998 ERROR 19233 --- [           main] c.r.j.i.t.returns.ReturnsServiceTest     : DataIntegrityViolationException
    2019-12-13 11:08:33.998 ERROR 19233 --- [           main] c.r.j.i.t.returns.ReturnsServiceTest     : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    2019-12-13 11:08:34.023  INFO 19233 --- [           main] c.r.j.i.t.returns.ReturnsServiceTest     :
```

Comment: For starters , remove the methods from your repositories, those are already provided by Spring Data JPA. Remove `@EnableTransactionManagement` (Spring Boot adds this automatically).

Comment: I believe the issue might be that you have too much stuff there. Try removing ``@Transactional`` from ``ReturnEntriesHistoryRepo`` and remove the extra stuff in the ``@Transactional`` annotation you used within ``ReturnsService``. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: @FilippoPossenti - Thank you for replying. I have tried your suggestion. It still does not work. It seems like save() and saveAll() methods have transactions implemented internally. When ReturnEntriesHistoryRepo.saveAll() fails, all records passed to saveAll rolled back, but the record inserted using ReturnHistoryRepo.save(), though inserted in same transactional method has got commited. Please suggest if I can stop those internal transactions from commiting

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks for replying. Tried your suggestion as well. It did not help either

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Declarative approach try Programmatic appraoach

Remove `@Transactional` from method where you want to perform the operations that are atomic.

then update your service method like this:

```
 import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;

 public int aBC(XYZ xyz) {
    try {
         //transaction 1
         //transaction 2
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Since this was not working,I have used the Hibernate session and transaction to make it atomic. I will try **TransactionAspectSupport** today and let you know